# Prove that the max area of a triangle inside a rectangle is half of the area of the rectangle

Tags: geometry, area

Let $ABCD$ be a rectangle, and points $PQR$ be inside the triangle(or on it's edges). I want to prove that the maximum area of the triangle $PQR$ is the area of the rectangle $ABCD$ divided by $2$.
When I tried to prove it, I said that the diagonal(wlog) $AC$ is the largest edge in $ABCD$ so it have to be in there, and from there it is quite easy to prove, but I don't understand how can I prove that because it is the largest so it must be a part of the triangle with max area?

- EDIT:

1. I was asked to try to prove again with the hints and here is what I got:
   If the largest edge(wlog) $PQ$, not on the perimeter, then we can extend the corners $P,Q$ to get a triangle with a greater altitude, and a greater width $PQ$, which will give us a greater area, but if $PQ$ on the perimeter then we can't extend it, thus it has to be on the perimeter.
2. Assume $P$ is not a corner, then, by the same principle as $1.$ we can extend the other two to the edges, and then extend them even more to the corners.
3. I don't know how to infer that.
   I know it's not ideal prove of what I've been asked, but I guess that's the best I can do.

Comment: It doesn't have to be. Any triangle with one side $AB$ and another vertex anywhere on side $CD$ also has the same area. You need a more refined argument.

Comment: Yes you are right! Yet, how do I prove that the max area of the triangle is half of the rectangles?

Comment: Approach I would take: 1/ Show that at the maximum, P, Q, R lie on the perimeter. 2/ Show that if P (resp Q, R) is not at a corner, then Q and R are at a corner. 3/ Hence, we're in the situation Michal described, and the area is 1/2.

Comment: I know that this site is to help people to get to their proves alone, but this is a prove that is all about the nuances of it, so it would be nice if you(or someone else) could help me with that, because I tend to get lost with those so called "trivial proofs"

Comment: Per site policy, please show your work and what you've tried, and where you got stuck at.

Comment: I did:) I know how this site works, and I didn't want to get downvotes(obv), so I said that what I thought about is to say that the diagonal should be in there, but I was wrong. Do you want me to edit to question, and try to prove with the clues you provided me earlier? I can do it, can you just tell me if that's what you want? @CalvinLin

Comment: Right, you were asking for me (or that's how I interpreted it) to help you with my hints, so please edit the question to work on my hints. EG hint 1 should be "obvious", but has to be dealt with in a technical manner.

Comment: @CalvinLin Sure! I'll do it ASAP(in about a hour or so, I just have h.w)

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3556334/the-area-of-the-triangle-is-less-than-30-cm2 also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/166713/if-any-triangle-has-area-at-most-1-points-can-be-covered-by-a-rectangle-of-are

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thank you so much! Is there a way I can close the question without closing it? I don't think I explained it too well.

Comment: If you could close it without closing it, then you could also prove that you are the Pope. What do you mean?

Comment: haha, I meant is there a way of closing a question without me losing the upvotes?

Comment: Closing a question has no effect on upvotes (or downvotes). If the question gets deleted, then the points go away. By the way, if you want to be sure I see a comment intended for me, you have to put @Gerry in it.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Gotcha! Calvin Lin already put his effort and answered the question, so instead of closing it, I'll just accept his answer. Because if I am not mistaken than his proof is different than the other proofs that you provided me. Thank you anyways!

Comment: "Closing a question" is a technical term on this website. A question can be closed by a moderator; a question can be closed by the votes of five users who have accumulated enough points to have acquired the vote-to-close privilege; and that's it. Since you fall into neither category, you couldn't close this question if you tried. You could *delete* this question, but that's an entirely different thing from *closing* it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The crux is that at the maximal case, then the line through (say) $R$ parallel to $PQ$ should have no points of the rectangle on the other side of the line.

> If there is a point $R'$ on the other side of the line, then the altitude is larger and hence the area $PQR'$ is larger.

Using that, prove the following Observations:

1. In the maximal case, P, Q, R lie on the perimeter of the rectangle.

   - This follows immediately from the crux, since any interior point would not have a line that separates the rectangle.
2. In the maximal case, if $P$ and $Q$ are not both endpoints of an edge, then $R$ is at a corner.

   - Again, this follows from the crux. Any edge is not parallel to $PQ$, so $R$ has to occur at an endpoint.
3. In the maximal case, there is a side of $PQR$ that is also a side of the rectangle.

   - If all three points are corners, then we are done.
   - Else, WLOG $R$ is not a corner, then applying the above to $RP$ and $RQ$, we get that $Q$ and $P$ are corners.

     - If they are corners of an edge, we are done.
     - If not, then $R$ is a corner by the above (which is a contradiction).
4. Finally, show that this triangle has the desired area.

Note: It is possible to argue Observation 3 directly from the Crux, but this build up felt more natural to me, especially for someone who didn't know how to approach this.

Answer (score 1):

First I will prove that the triangle with the largest area whose vertices are on the edges of the rectangle is $1/2$ of the area of the rectangle

If a triangle has 2 vertices on the same same side It is easy to see that this triangle is  contained in a triangle with area  $= 1/2 $ the area of the rectangle

[image]
In this case $PQR$ is contained in $CBQ$

---

If the triangle happen to have each of its vertices on 3 different sides Then

[image]

It is sufficient to prove that this triangle has less area than half the area of $EQPC$ which is less or equal to Half area of $ABCD$ (The case where they are equal
only happen when on of the vertices  of the triangle happen to be the one of the vertices of the rectangle   )

$$y\ge r , \ x\ge l$$ it is sufficient to prove that $$rx+(y-r)l + (x-l) y -xy \ge 0 $$ i.e the of the area of the rectangle $EQPC$ except the blue triangle $PQR$ is greater than half the area of $EQPC$
$$rx+ly-lr + yx-yl -xy \ge 0 $$
$$rx-lr   \ge 0$$
$$r(x-l) \ge 0 $$
$$x\ge l$$ which is true

---

If all or some of the vertices are inside the rectangle then

[image]

If the triangle $PQR$ is inside the rectangle $ABCD$ it is contained in a rectangle such that all of its vertices are on the sides of this rectangle which has less area than $ABCD$

By the previous argument $$\text{area } PQR \le \frac{1}{2} \text{area } HIPJ \le \frac{1}{2} \text{area } ABCD $$

Comment: İ did a similar sketch of proof yesterday but didnt write. What do you use to draw figures? One pic worths thousand words...

Comment: @BobDobbs I use GeoGebra Calculator in geometry mode